# How to extract string after certain word in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get a reference number inside a string which is in most cases precedented by "Ref." or something similar.

e.g.:

> Explorer II Ref.16570 Box

[regex with further examples](https://regex101.com/r/qO3NKM/3)

The problem is that there are many different variations[1](https://regex101.com/r/qO3NKM/3) as this is user generated content. How could I retrieve the number with python which is precented by e.g. `Ref.`?

The number/string is not always the same pattern e.g. numbers. .They might be mixed with characters and dots and slashes but for a human eye there is almost always such a number in each line identifiable.

E.g.:

```
Ref.16570
Ref. 16570
Referenz 216570
Referenz 01 733 7653 4159-07 4 26
331.12.42.51.01.002
166.0173
AB012012/BB01
Ref. 167.021
PAM00292
14000M
L3.642.4.56.6
161.559.50
801
666
753
116400GV
Ref.: 231.10.39.21.03.002
3233
Ref: 233.32.41.21.01.002
T081.420.97.057.01
16750
... almost each line in the example provided contains a certain ID
```

A small amount of false positives would not be a problem.

Comment: Do you need to `match` or `extract` ?

Comment: The link you shared doesn't show any further examples. It would be better if you could share some more examples in your question.

Comment: Probably you are looking for `Ref(?:erenz)?\. *(\d+)`. It shouldn't start with `^`. What you need is in 1st capturing group.

Comment: @PedroLobito I am looking to extract the number. It is always one per line. The example shows the titles of several cases which are typical. Each contains a reference number.

Comment: Do [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/SFasuC/1) work for u?

Comment: Does not return a hit so far. @ShabbirKhan I added 250 more lines with examples under the second link.

Comment: In your examples after `Ref` there are numbers like `5215`, numbers with symbols like `220.12.41.21.03.001`, `01 733 7653 4159-07 4 26 34EB`, and `T019.430.16.031.01.`. Add to the question what data you want to find - only numbers or any variations or some variations?

Comment: Any variation of it. Almost any line contains a ref number in different formats (depending on model). Usually it is precedented by Ref. but might also be strange string like the ones you mentioned. My goal is to get as many as possible with as little as possible false positives.

Comment: *...but for a human eye there is almost always such a number in each line identifiable.* no sir. Not unless you give us some rules.

Comment: @revo Thank you for the hint. I added some examples to the questions and also altered the regex within the link to illustrate better what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure if you need to `match` or `extract`, but `Ref\.?([ \d.]+)` will extract any digits after `Ref` (case insensitive), i.e.:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r"Ref\.?([ \d.]+)", subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

---

```
['16570', '16570', '167.021', '3527']
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SFasuC/3)
[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Qtg)

---

**Regex Explanation**
[image]

Comment: I want to extract the reference number. For a better explanation I took your regex, added some code and updated the link within the question. You can see that there are certain maches now, but with different color and not all ref ids are matche. E.g. L.3.674.4.50.0 is one I want to get and also 331.12.42.51.01.002. Will update the question in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick:

```
import re
str = 'Explorer II Ref.16570 Box'
m = re.match('Ref\.[0-9]+', str)
if m:
    print(m.group(0)[4:])
```

For more info:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: I am getting: >>> print(m.group(0)[4:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Then the string likely doesn't have a match. I've updated my answer to account for this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It collects all the data after `Ref` till one of pre-defined stoppers. Stoppers are used because the question does not contain clear definition of what data is reference (`not always the same pattern`, `might be mixed with`, `for a human eye there is almost always`). I guess additional processing of matches is needed to extract actual references more accurately.

```
import re

ref_re = re.compile('(?P<ref_keyword>Referenz|Ref\.|Ref)[ ]*(?P<ref_value>.*?)(?P<ref_stopper> - | / |,|\n)')

with open('1.txt', mode='r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    data = file.read()

for match in ref_re.finditer(data):
    print('key:', match.group('ref_keyword'))
    print('value:', match.group('ref_value'))
    # print('stopper:', match.group('ref_stopper'))
```

Output starts with the lines:

```
key: Ref.
value: 16570 Box&Papiere mit Revision
key: Ref.
value: 16570 Box&Papiere mit Revision
key: Referenz
value: 216570 mit schwarzem Zifferblatt 
key: Referenz
value: 01 733 7653 4159-07 4 26 34EB 
key: Ref.
value: 167.021
key: Ref.
value: 3527
key: Referenz
value: 01 733 7653 4159-07 4 26 34EB
key: Ref.
value: 16570 Box&Papiere mit Revision
```